# Appending to dictonary with class?

Tags: python

```
class Clinic:
    def __init__(self, medicationList):
        self._medicationList = {}
    def addMedication(self, medication):
        self._medicationList.append(medication)

def main():
     m1 = ('CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3)
     m2 = ('DM01', 'Dex-2 trimethorphan-0', 0.25, 15.0, 2)
     m3 = ('LH03', 'Lyso-X Hydrochloride', 1.00, 10.0, 1)
     cl = Clinic()
     cl.addMedication('CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3)
     print(c1)

main()
```

I am trying to append the medicine into the `_medicationList`. How do I go about doing it?  So the dictionary will be something like

```
{m1 : ['CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3 ] , m2 : ['DM01', 'Dex-2 trimethorphan-0', 0.25, 15.0, 2]}`
```

Comment: `self._medicationList` is not a list

Comment: change it to `self._medicationList = []`. Also, in python variable and function names are named `lowercase_with_underscores` not `camelCase` so really it should be `self._medication_list = []`

Comment: You are passing 5 arguments to `cl.addMedication` but `addMedication` takes one. It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want `medicationList` to be a list of tuples?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I would like medicationList to be implemented as a dictionary.

Comment: **Please clarify your question.** See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: The way your code is, the `cl = Clinic()` won't work because it doesn't pass a `medicationList` argument as required to the class' `__init__()` method.

Comment: What's `m1` in the dictionary?

Comment: @ElwinLee well, then `dict` objects don't have an `.append` method. Are you asking how to add a key-value pair to a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to be using a list instead of a dictionary.  Maybe something like this?

```
from typing import List, Tuple

Medication = Tuple[str, str, float, float, int]


class Clinic:
    def __init__(self):
        self._medications: List[Medication] = []

    def add_medication(self, medication: Medication) -> None:
        self._medications.append(medication)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self._medications)


def main() -> None:
    m1 = ('CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3)
    m2 = ('DM01', 'Dex-2 trimethorphan-0', 0.25, 15.0, 2)
    m3 = ('LH03', 'Lyso-X Hydrochloride', 1.00, 10.0, 1)
    cl = Clinic()
    for m in m1, m2, m3:
        cl.add_medication(m)
    print(cl)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want it to be a dict instead of a list, maybe something more like this?

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple

Medication = Tuple[str, str, float, float, int]


class Clinic:
    def __init__(self):
        self._medications: Dict[str, Medication] = {}

    def add_medication(self, name: str, medication: Medication) -> None:
        self._medications[name] = medication

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self._medications)


def main() -> None:
    m1 = ('CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3)
    m2 = ('DM01', 'Dex-2 trimethorphan-0', 0.25, 15.0, 2)
    m3 = ('LH03', 'Lyso-X Hydrochloride', 1.00, 10.0, 1)
    cl = Clinic()
    cl.add_medication("m1", m1)
    cl.add_medication("m2", m2)
    cl.add_medication("m3", m3)
    print(cl)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I would like to medicationList to be implemented as a dictionary. So the dictionary will be something like {m1 : ['CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3 ] , m2 : ['DM01', 'Dex-2 trimethorphan-0', 0.25, 15.0, 2]}

Comment: @ElwinLee that makes no sense, why would it be `m1`??

Answer (score 0):

```
class Clinic:
   def __init__(self):
       self._medication_list = {}
   def add_medication(self, medication):
       self._medication_list[medication[0]] = medication[1:]
   def get_medication_list(self):
       return self._medication_list

def main():
   m1 = ('m1','CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3)
   m2 = ('m2','DM01', 'Dex-2 trimethorphan-0', 0.25, 15.0, 2)
   m3 = ('m3','LH03', 'Lyso-X Hydrochloride', 1.00, 10.0, 1)
   lst = [m1,m2,m3]
   cl = Clinic()
   for m in lst:
       cl.add_medication(m)
   print(cl.get_medication_list())

main()
```

is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ElwinLee glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

1.Your `self._medicationList` is not a `list` first (I think you show assign to an empty dictionary instead)

2. Your `addMedication()` function takes only one parameter, you've provided 6, I guess you should use '*'

**Here is the code that works, try running it:**

```
class Clinic:
    def __init__(self):
        self.medicationList = dict()

    def addMedication(self, name, *medication):
        self.medicationList.update({name: list(medication)})

def main():
        m1 = ('CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3)
        m2 = ('DM01', 'Dex-2 trimethorphan-0', 0.25, 15.0, 2)
        m3 = ('LH03', 'Lyso-X Hydrochloride', 1.00, 10.0, 1)
        cl = Clinic()
        cl.addMedication('CP12', 'Chloro-6 pheniramine-X', 0.08, 4.0, 3)
        print(cl.medicationList)

main()
```